# Centering a layout in a ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, listview-adapter

I dont get it - I cannot align the `RelativeLayout` in the `ListView` - that is I want to center the `RelativeLayout` that holds and image and some textviews.

The `RelativeLayout` is still on the lefthand-side of the screen, though the listview-width should match the parent. What could be wrong?

Here's the xml, for the list item layout in the adapter.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout_os_id"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/os_listview_imageview1_id"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/os_listview_imageview1_id"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/os_listview_name_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nougat"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/os_listview_version_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="7.0"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/os_listview_api_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="24"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/os_listview_release_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="2016"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

And the `ListView` is here in the following layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    tools:context="se.listview.stude.listviewtest180303.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/os_listView_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Edit: this is how it looks the list item in the design-mode in android-studio.

[image]

Comment: Try changing width of item to match_parent

Comment: @java i have updated the answer please check update if it works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this as rootLayout of your item :-

```
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android
        ="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/relativeLayout_os_id"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="center"

     >
```

You would get the same output..

Also in your activity put **listView** width as `match_parent`

Comment: it does not work, thanks anyway. I think I've done the right thing in the adpapters layout - see update soon

Comment: did you try it anyway ?? i am not getting any reason why it shouldnt workm. @java

Comment: i have seen it.. @java what output did you get ?? and did you replace `layout_gravity` with `gravity` ? as i have mentioned ??

Comment: Now it works, you are completely right - sorry I missed to change from layout_gravity to gravity :-p

Answer (score 0):

I think here's the layout that you want. Keeping it as simple as possible.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout_os_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/os_listview_imageview1_id"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/os_listview_imageview1_id"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/os_listview_name_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nougat" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/os_listview_version_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="7.0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/os_listview_api_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="24" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/os_listview_release_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2016" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```